# SQLITE3+ Catnap + MonoTouch alter table add column pb

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I don't understand,
here is my problem :

```
   string sql="alter table mytable add CellarPosition integer; alter table mytable add Quantity integer;  alter table mytable add CreatingYear integer; alter table mytable add OptimalYear integer;";

                var command = new DbCommandSpec().SetCommandText(sql);

                unitofwork.Session.ExecuteNonQuery(command);
```

the only first alter table executes but the others does not .
any suggestion?????

Comment: On a slightly related topic, it is customary to accept answers in the StackOverflow community. It is possible that some users will shun answering your questions if you do not accept any. You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Please see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that SQLite might not be able to chain several `Alter table` queries. I'd suggest doing them one at a time for simplicity.

Comment: Event I do them one after one, it does not work only the first one works

Comment: I don't know Catnap. Can you see if there is an error message from sqlite after each attempt?

Comment: the problem that there is no erreur, no exception handled ,the first statement execute but the other fails

Comment: Can you post your original table definition, please?

Comment: CREATE TABLE myTable (
Id integer  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
Version TEXT)

Comment: Here is the solution : I read the script from a txt file, the problem is the with the \n in txt file

Answer (score 0):

If it had been MySQL, you would do something like this:
alter table mytable
 add CellarPosition integer
 ,add Quantity integer
 ,add CreatingYear integer
 ,add OptimalYear integer;